# How to get a native UITableView with UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle in React Native?

Tags: ios, react-native, uitableview

I want to build something like this with React Native:
[image]

(image source https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/views/tables/)
How can this be done in React Native? Do I need 3rd party libraries for that or is it possible with the "core" React Native?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own component without using 3rd party libraries.

```
renderRow = () => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
          <Image source={// The left icon source here}/>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.content}>
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Title</Text>
            <Text style={styles.subtitle}>SubTitle</Text>
          </View>
          <Image source={// The right arrow source here} />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    padding: 10,
    height: 70,
  },
  imageContainer: {
    height: '100%',
    width: 70,
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  content: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flex: 1,
    borderBottomColor: 'gray',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
  },
  title: {
    color: 'black',
    fontWeight: 'normal',
  },
  subtitle: {
    color: 'lightgray',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
})
```

Or you can find an example of UITableViewCell in `NativeBase` (ListItem component) https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#list-def-headref

Answer (score 1):

React Native [bridges](https://reactnative.dev/docs/intro-react-native-components) to UIView and UIScrollView but not UITableView. The reason for this is that

> UITableView API is not well suited for the asynchronous nature of ReactNative, and the resulting code was pretty gross
>
> https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/332#issuecomment-86991307

The only solutions are to

1. use a component that wraps native UITableView (e.g. [react-native-tableview](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-tableview))
2. use a component that mimics the look-and-feel of UITableView (e.g. [react-native-tableview-simple])(https://github.com/Purii/react-native-tableview-simple)
3. depart from UITableView and implement your own visual design (using pure RN [FlatList](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist) or e.g. Nativebase [FlatList](https://docs.nativebase.io/flat-list))
4. ask/help RN to provide an official component for bridging to native iOS UITableView (and Android ListView).

The first is of course great in terms of UX but is not cross-platform (also apparently [no longer actively maintained](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-tableview/issues/218)). The second will make your app look dated when Apple inevitably evolves the native appearance in new versions of iOS. So personally I would shy away from either of those.